# Validate a date range within MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-range

*(This question may seem easy or kind of noobish, by that I pardon my ignorance.)*

I used PDO query to use `SELECT` then fetch some values, it comes to a point that I need to fetch only some entries that within its start date and end date.

My database

```
+----------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| id (INT) | title (VARCHAR) | start_date (VARCHAR) | end_date (VARCHAR) |
+----------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|    1     |     buddy       |     2012-11-26       |     2012-11-30     |
|    2     |     metro       |     2012-12-05       |     2012-12-20     |
|    3     |     justin      |     2012-11-28       |     2012-12-01     |
+----------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

My query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT title, start_date, end_date FROM debts WHERE start_date >= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE()";
```

What I want to achieve is whenever the `start_date` is today or greater but not exceeding the `end_date` it will be valid. This will return the row for `id 1`, however if I change the `start_date` to `2012-11-25`, it will fail due to the first condition on `AND`. I'm really confuse on this since I am new to this, is there any built-in function to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: start_date >= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE().Sorry, I didn't understand that part

Comment: use date_format() when comparing dates, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: What do you mean with "it will fail"...do you get an error? If yes, which one?

Comment: Pardon, no error thrown, it works but not what I wanted to be. I edited my post for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better:

SELECT title, start_date, end_date FROM debts
WHERE date(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Comment: Thus between means it includes the date specified on `start_date` / `end_date`?

Comment: Yes, and it uses indexes on start_date and end_date fieldsRead more here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, start_date, end_date FROM debts
WHERE start_date >= CURDATE() AND end_date <= CURDATE()
```